# Convex combination of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, orthogonal-matrices

How would I show that the convex combination of orthogonal matrixes has spectral norm $ \leq 1$? (I have some idea how to do it ... but right now I'm stuck). Also, how would I prove that the unit spectral norm ball is a convex set?

Comment: It is not true. $I$ and $-I$ have norm one, but $\frac{1}{2}I + \frac{1}{2}(-I) = 0$ which has norm zero.

Comment: Did you mean norm $\le 1$ by any chance?

Comment: Yes. Apologies, I meant spectral norm atmost 1. I'll edit the question.

Comment: The unit spectral norm ball is a spectrahedron. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is orthogonal, then $\|A\| = 1$ (because $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$ for all $x$).

Suppose $A,B$ are orthogonal and $\mu \in [0,1]$.

Then $\|\mu A + (1-\mu)B \| \le \|\mu A \| + \| (1-\mu)B \| = \mu \|A\| + (1-\mu) \|B\|= 1 + (1-\mu) = 1$.

Any norm ball is convex  because the function $x \mapsto \|x\|$ is convex, and if we let $\phi(x) = \|x\|$, then we see that the unit ball is given by $\phi^{-1} (-\infty,1]$, and hence convex (since the level sets of a convex function are convex).

Alternatively, you could note that if $\|A\| \le 1$, $\|B\| \le 1$, then the same formula above (with the second last $=$ replaced by $\le$) shows that $\|\mu A + (1-\mu)B \| \le 1$.