# Maximize $\langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle$ subject to $\| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, spectral-norm

> Given $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$,
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1\end{array}$$

---

Since $\| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1$ is equivalent to $\sigma_{\max} (\mathrm X ) \leq 1$, which is equivalent to $\lambda_{\max} (\mathrm X^\top \mathrm X) \leq 1$, we have

$$1 - \lambda_{\max} (\mathrm X^\top \mathrm X) = \lambda_{\min} (\mathrm I_n - \mathrm X^\top \mathrm X)\geq 0$$

and, thus,

$$\mathrm I_n - \mathrm X^\top \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n$$

Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) test for positive semidefiniteness, we obtain the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}$$

Hence, we have the following [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}\end{array}$$

Is this correct? Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You reformulate an inequality constraint. The equality constraint is not convex and can therefore not be cast as an LMI.

Comment: @LinAlg Would the equality constraint define the *boundary* of the spectrahedron defined by the LMI?

Comment: Yes. The key here is the formula following "and, thus,".

Comment: It seems to me that you are formulating a relaxation of the original problem.

Comment: $A=0$ is a nasty case which destroys a claim that it is correct, but the maximum in non-trivial case is attained at the border of the feasible set which means you can replace the equality with an inequality in this simple program

Comment: @Johan Good point. I will replace the equality with an inequality, then.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and the standard approach to address this using semidefinite programming.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186979/339790

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be computed in closed-form via SVD. Indeed, given a matrix norm $\|.\|$ on $\mathbb C^{n,m}$, there is always a corresponding dual norm (i.e on the dual space $\mathbb C^{m,n}$) given by

$$\|A\|^{D} := \max_{\|X\| \le 1}\langle A, X\rangle_{\text{F}},
$$
where $\langle A, X\rangle_{\text{F}} := \text{trace}(AX^T)$ is the Frobenius / Hilbert-Schmidt inner product. In particular, it's not hard to show that  $\|A\|_2^D = \|A\|_* := \sum_{k}\sigma_k(A)$, the nuclear norm of $A$.

Comment: Nice answer.  Here's a question that asks to show the dual of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158798/show-that-the-dual-norm-of-spectral-norm-is-nuclear-norm

Comment: Nice pointer. This bails me out of the debt of having to write that part of the solution. Also, the algebra therein contained is really instructive.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\sum_i \lambda_i u_i v_i^T$ be the SVD of $A$. The nuclear norm of $A$
is by definition the sum of the singular values, $\sum_i \lambda_i$.

- The fact that the maximum of your optimization problem
  is at most the nuclear norm of $A$ follows from
  $$\langle A, X\rangle = trace(A^TX) =\sum_i \lambda_i v_i^T X u_i \le \sum_i \lambda_i
  $$
  by the triangle inequality because $X$ has operator norm at most one, so $|v_i^T X u_i|\le 1$.
- The fact that $\sum_i \lambda_i$ can be achieved for some matrix $X$ with operator norm at most one follows by taking $X= \sum_i u_iv_i^T$.

Comment: Aren't $u$ and $v$ swapped in your first bullet point? I.e. $\mathrm{trace}(A^TX) = \sum_i \lambda_i \mathrm{trace}(v_i u_i^T X) = \sum_i \lambda_i u_i^T X \, v_i$.