# Nearest semi-orthogonal matrix using the entry-wise $ {\ell}_{1} $ norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, orthogonal-matrices, non-convex-optimization, stiefel-manifolds

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $M$ ($m \geq n$), the **nearest** [semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix) matrix problem in $m \times n$ matrix $R$ is

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| M - R \|_F\\ \text{subject to} & R^T R = I_n\end{array}$$

A solution can be found by using [Lagrangian](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Nearest_Orthonormal_Matrix.pdf) or [polar decomposition](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Math128/NearestQ.pdf), and is known to be

$$\hat{R} := M(M^TM)^{-1/2}$$

If $\|\cdot\|_F$ is replaced by the entry-wise $1$-norm

$$\|A\|_1 := \|\operatorname{vec}(A)\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |A_{i,j}|$$

the problem becomes

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| M - R \|_1\\ \text{subject to} & R^T R = I_n\end{array}}$$

What do we know about the solutions in this case? Is $\hat{R}$ still a solution? If the solution is something else, do analytic forms or approximations exist? Any insight or direction to literature is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following non-convex optimization problem in (non-fat) $\mathrm X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm A \|_1\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X^\top \mathrm X = \mathrm I_n\end{array}

where (non-fat) $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ is given. The feasible region, defined by $\mathrm X^\top \mathrm X = \mathrm I_n$, is a [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) whose convex hull is defined by $\mathrm X^\top \mathrm X \preceq \mathrm I_n$, or, [equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790), by the inequality $\| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1$. Hence, a **convex relaxation** of the original optimization problem is

$$\boxed{\qquad \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm A \|_1\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1\end{array} \qquad}$$

Via the Schur complement test for positive semidefiniteness, $\mathrm X^\top \mathrm X \preceq \mathrm I_n$ can be rewritten as the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}$$

and, thus,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm A \|_1\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}\end{array}$$

Introducing variable $\mathrm Y \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, we obtain the following [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) in $\mathrm X, \mathrm Y \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle 1_m 1_n^\top, \mathrm Y \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & - \mathrm Y \leq \mathrm X - \mathrm A \leq \mathrm Y\\ & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm X\\ \mathrm X^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}\end{array}$$

---

#### Numerical experiments

The following Python + NumPy + [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org) code solves the convex relaxation of the original problem:

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np

(m,n) = (30,3)

A = np.random.rand(m,n)

X = Variable(m,n)

# define optimization problem
prob = Problem( Minimize(norm(X-A,1)), [ norm(X,2) <= 1 ])

# solve optimization problem
print prob.solve()
print prob.status

# print results
print "X = \n", X.value
print "Spectral norm of X = ", np.linalg.norm(X.value,2)
print "X.T * X = \n", (X.value).T * (X.value)
print "Round(X.T * X) = \n", np.round((X.value).T * (X.value), 3)
```

Unfortunately, it produces

```
X.T * X = 
[[ 0.50912521  0.22478268  0.25341844]
 [ 0.22478268  0.4961892   0.2654229 ]
 [ 0.25341844  0.2654229   0.46896397]]
```

which is quite "far" from the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. This is disappointing.

However, using the **Frobenius** norm instead of the entry-wise $1$-norm:

```
prob = Problem( Minimize(norm(X-A,'fro')), [ norm(X,2) <= 1 ])
```

we obtain the following output

```
3.85187827124
optimal
X = 
[[ 0.13146134 -0.14000011  0.32874275]
 [-0.01234834  0.11837379  0.06604536]
 [-0.10490978  0.10542352  0.25211362]
 [ 0.25263062  0.14707194  0.03884215]
 [ 0.00181182  0.4702248  -0.20126385]
 [ 0.13013444 -0.07199484  0.08727077]
 [ 0.19077548 -0.01423872 -0.05960523]
 [ 0.2865637  -0.00202074  0.02844798]
 [ 0.01602302  0.04395754  0.00154713]
 [ 0.17932924  0.30926775 -0.05940074]
 [ 0.42908676 -0.21953956  0.12394825]
 [ 0.1255695   0.16415755  0.14634119]
 [ 0.28144817  0.08592836  0.08426443]
 [ 0.18209884  0.25983065 -0.02550957]
 [ 0.11077068 -0.10874038  0.23649308]
 [ 0.01565326  0.14043185  0.01186364]
 [-0.04374642  0.20360714  0.01079417]
 [-0.00440237  0.17746665  0.12931808]
 [ 0.18899948  0.08389032  0.23493301]
 [ 0.25802202  0.16171055  0.09263858]
 [-0.01921053  0.26863496  0.13077382]
 [-0.11175044  0.06137184  0.32758781]
 [-0.20321302  0.37803842  0.17629377]
 [-0.09301606 -0.0783033   0.36603431]
 [-0.00572361  0.17620931 -0.04822991]
 [ 0.24944001  0.18830197 -0.05522287]
 [-0.2049578   0.1091767   0.38943593]
 [ 0.36823908 -0.10026829  0.04425441]
 [ 0.03582131  0.03531081  0.08337656]
 [-0.07315648 -0.0739467   0.35741916]]
Spectral norm of X =  1.00018499995
X.T * X = 
[[ 0.99843209 -0.00168429 -0.0019862 ]
 [-0.00168429  0.99833293 -0.00222193]
 [-0.0019862  -0.00222193  0.99790575]]
Round(X.T * X) = 
[[ 0.998 -0.002 -0.002]
 [-0.002  0.998 -0.002]
 [-0.002 -0.002  0.998]]
```

where $\rm X^\top X$ is now quite "close" to the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

I did perform many numerical experiments, with several values for $m$ and $n$. My conclusions:

- Minimizing the Frobenius norm worked rather satisfactorily for **very tall** matrices ($m \gg n$).
- Unfortunately, minimizing the entry-wise $1$-norm failed in **all** experiments I performed.

By "worked" and "failed" I mean that the solution of the **relaxed** convex problem is a solution of the **original** (non-convex) optimization problem or not, respectively.

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent with the original question.  Your $A$ is the original poster's $M$.

Comment: My comment was merely there to help any reader who was confused by change in notation.

Comment: I'm with Brian on this one—the notation change is unnecessarily distracting. As for using $m$ and $M$ at the same time, well, that would throw me off every time I need to formulate a big-$M$ method! ;-)

Comment: $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle 1_m 1_n^\top, \mathrm Y \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & - \mathrm Y \leq \mathrm R - \mathrm M \leq \mathrm Y\\ & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_m & \mathrm R\\ \mathrm R^\top & \mathrm I_n\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+n}\end{array}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Is there a projection onto the [Stiefel Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) (Also the space of [Semi Orthogonal Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix))?

Comment: @Royi That sounds Procrustes-like. Please post a question on that so that I know which objective and constraints you have in mind, and then send me the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Reformulate the problem by constructing the $R$ matrix in terms of an unconstrained matrix $U$ such that the constraint is always satisfied:
$$R = U(U^TU)^{-1/2}\quad\implies\quad R^TR=I$$
Then optimize with respect to the new unconstrained variable $U.\;$ Since $R$ is independent of $\,\|U\|\,$ controlling the growth of $\,\|U\|\,$ (via normalization) will be important for numerical algorithms.

The (sub)gradient of the Manhattan norm of $X$ is given by
$$\eqalign{
\mu &= \|X\|_1 \\
d\mu &= {\rm sign}(X):dX \;\;\doteq\;\; S:dX \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
and the sign function
$${\rm sign}(z) = 
\begin{cases}
+{\tt1}\quad{\rm if}\;z\ge 0 \\
-{\tt1}\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
is applied elementwise.

Now calculate the differential of $R$
$$\eqalign{
B &= (U^TU)^{1/2} = B^T
 \qquad&\big\{{\rm square\,root}\big\} \\
B^2 &= U^TU \\
B\,dB+dB\,B &= U^TdU+dU^TU
 \qquad&\big\{{\rm differentials}\big\} \\
(I_n\otimes B+B\otimes I_n)\,db
 &= \Big(I_n\otimes U^T+(U^T\otimes I_n)K\Big)\,du
 \qquad&\big\{{\rm vectorized}\big\} \\
db &= P\,du \\
\\
R &= UB^{-1} \\
dR &= dU\,B^{-1} - UB^{-1}dB\,B^{-1} \\
   &= dU\,B^{-1} - R\,dB\,B^{-1} \\
dr &= (B^{-1}\otimes I_m)\,du - (B^{-1}\otimes R)\,db \\
   &= \Big((B^{-1}\otimes I_m) - (B^{-1}\otimes R)P\Big)\,du \\
   &= Q\,du \\
}$$
where $K$ is the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the vectorization of a matrix transpose via the Kronecker product.

Finally, let $\,X=(R-M)\,$ and calculate the gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
d\mu &= S:dX \\
  &= S:dR \\
  &= s:dr
 &\qquad\big\{{\rm vectorized}\big\} \\
  &= s:Q\,du \\
  &= Q^Ts:du \\
\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial u}  &= Q^Ts
 &\qquad\big\{{\rm gradient}\big\} \\
\\
}$$
Now use a sub-gradient method initialized with the Frobenius solution
$$\eqalign{
U_0 &= M \\
}$$
and iterated as
$$\eqalign{
B_k &= (U_k^TU_k)^{1/2} \\
R_k &= U_kB_k^{-1}
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\big\{{\rm current/best\,solution}\big\} \\
P_k
 &= (I_n\otimes B_k+B_k\otimes I_n)^{-1}\Big(I_n\otimes U_k^T+(U_k^T\otimes I_n)K\Big) \\
Q_k &= \Big((B_k^{-1}\otimes I_m) - (B_k^{-1}\otimes R_k)P_k\Big) \\
g_k &= Q_k^T\,{\rm vec}\Big({\rm sign}(R_k-M)\Big) \\
w_k &= \operatorname{vec}(U_k) - \lambda_kg_k
 \qquad\;\big\{{\rm subgradient\,step}\big\} \\
u_{k+1} &= \frac{w_k}{\|w_k\|_2}
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\big\{{\rm normalize}\big\} \\
U_{k+1} &= {\rm reshape}\big(\,u_{k+1},\, {\rm shape}(U_k)\,\big) \\
}$$