# Give conditions for a map defined on a domaine $D$ is a contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis, differential, jacobian, contraction-operator

Let $D=[0,1]^n$, and $f:D \rightarrow D$ a $C^1$ map.

What is the condtion for the Jacobian of $f$ to be a Contraction map, i.e

$$\exists\, 1>r>0\,, ||f(x)-f(y)||\leq r||x-y||, \, \text{For all } \, x,y\in D$$

Comment: Do you need a necessary condition or a criterion?
Can you edit your question as to give us more context please?

Comment: Ok, I will change the context

Comment: @OlivierRoche The criterion is that eigenvalues of the Jacobian should be less strictly than $1$, but I'm stuck proving it

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient condition is that the norm of the Jacobian is bounded by $r$ on $D$. This is an immediate consequence of the [Mean value theorem in several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).

Obviously, you need to consider the [matrix norm induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) by your $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ norm to apply the Mean value theorem quoted above.

The converse is also true as if $\Vert J_f(x_0)\Vert > r$ at $x_0 \in D$, you'll be able to find a point $x$ "close to" $x_0$ such that  $$\Vert f(x) - f(x_0) \Vert > r \Vert x - x_0 \vert$$

Answer (score 0):

Mixing mathcounterexamples.net 's answer and this [method to compute an operator norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670350/operator-norm-calculation-for-simple-matrix), one gets following criterion :

If the square root of all eigenvalues of  $J_f(x)^T J_f(x)$ is bounded by $r$, then $f$ is $r$-Lipschitz.