# Finding solution to $Xa=b$ where $X$ has to be symmetric positive-definite

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, covariance

I want to reconstruct a $K\times K$ matrix $X$, knowing that that:

1. $X1=b$ ($1$ and $b$ are $K\times 1$)
2. $X$ is symmetric positive definite.

I understand this is a kind of under-determined system, but I am wondering whether and how I can find a solution $X$, such that $X$ is symmetric and positive-definite? Or do I need to add more information? Can a solution be unique, or is there anyway an infinity of those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the following semidefinite program (SDP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \mathbb 1 = \mathrm b\\ & \mathrm X  \succeq \mathrm O\end{array}$$

The solution set is the intersection of the positive semidefinite cone with a hyperplane.

Comment: great, thanks! Can you give a quick intuition/explanation why minimizing 0? And you don't mention the symmetry in the constraints, is that automatically satisfied? Finally, if I may ask, any specific method/algorithms to recommend, ideally in R? Thanks!!!

Comment: Minimizing $0$ because it's a *feasibility* problem, not an optimization problem. One only cares about getting a point in the feasible region. There's no cost to minimize. Positive semidefiniteness usually implies symmetry. Since the skew-symmetric part of a matrix contributes nothing to a quadratic form, it only makes sense discussing the definiteness of symmetric matrices. I never used R for optimization. If you use MATLAB, try using CVX. If you use Python, there's CVXPY. In R, there's [Rdsdp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdsdp/).

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification, much appreciated!

Comment: I made a new post about the specific implementation of this, in case you want to look at it would be great, thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416911/semidefinite-programming-writing-down-a-feasibility-program-in-dsdp-or-csdp

Comment: @Matifou If you try to use Python + CVXPY, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2776808/339790).

Comment: One more question... do you know how one would add the constraint that the diagonal elements are non-negative? Can that be cast into the sdp constraint? Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou From Sylvester's criterion, it follows that the positive semidefiniteness constraint on matrix $\rm X$ does encapsulate the constraints you mentioned.