# Writing down a feasibility semidefinite program in DSDP or CSDP

Tags: positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I am trying to solve a simple semidefinite programming problem (following this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414346/finding-solution-to-xa-b-where-x-has-to-be-symmetric-positive-definite/3414371?noredirect=1#comment7022311_3414371)):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X \mathbb 1 = \mathrm b\\ & \mathrm X  \succeq \mathrm O\end{array}$$

I am using R, either package [Rdsdp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcsdp/index.html) or [Rcsdp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcsdp/index.html) using corresponding libraries DSDP and CSDP, and have trouble formulating the problem. In particular, both commands expect X to be in *block-diagonal form*, and has a  `K` parameter, that specifies

- `s`: *A vector of integers listing the dimension of positive semidefinite cone blocks.*
- `l`: *A scaler integer indicating the dimension of the linear nonnegative cone block.*

I am not sure how to relate my problem to the block-diagonal form of X (and hence C and A), and how to specify this K. So far, for a $3\times3$ matrix, I wrote:

- `C`: matrix of 0, 1 row and 6 cols, 6 representing unique elements in the $3\times3$ original matrix.
- `A`: matrix of ones or zeros, 3 rows and 6 cols. First row selects the first three elements of x: $[1,1,1,0,0,0]$.

My code is:

```
library(Rdsdp)

b <- c(7.0, 6.5, 5.5) # the contraint, only vector I am sure about
C=matrix(0,1,15)
A=matrix(c(c(1,1,1,0,0,0),
           c(0,1,0,1,1,0),
           c(0, 0, 1, 0,1, 1)),
         nrow=3, ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
K <-  list(s=c(1,2), l=3) # me random guessing

result_mat = dsdp(A,b,C,K)

round(result_mat$X,3)
#> [1]        3.036        2.147        1.816        2.181        2.171
#> [6]        0.756        0.756 49945388.956
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com may be a better place to ask this question. It has an [R](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) tag.

Comment: On the other hand, the creator of [CSDP](https://github.com/coin-or/csdp/) is a member of Math SE and often posts on questions on SDP.

Comment: yes, it's a little an in-between case! But the `semidefinite-programming` tag has ten times more posts here than there, and eminent members. Anyway, this is not really specific to R, but rather to the mathematical formulation as expected by `DSDP` or `CSDP` :-)