# Help with SDP and Schur's Complement

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, schur-complement

I'm trying so hard to understand SDP and how Schur's complement is used and what does it even mean? Is there a good and simple reference with some numerical examples that can answer my question especially that I'm not that great in linear algebra. I mean, what does Schur's complement even mean in words? I don't understand what does it do? Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what "explaining what it means in words would mean" in this context. How would you explain what a quadratic function is "in words"?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) regarding the Schur complement?

Comment: What am I trying to say is that I don't understand why do we need it? What is its physical interpretation?

Comment: Most things involving matrices don't have a "physical interpretation". In its general usage, the Schur complement does not have a physical interpretation.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790).

Answer (score 3):

The Schur complement, in a nutshell, is about breaking down the condition that a big matrix is positive into the "simpler" condition that two smaller matrices are positive.

Here's an examination of the Schur complement in the context of [quadric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric). Suppose we are given an equation of the form
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^3 a_{ij} x_i x_j = 1.
$$
Without loss of generality, we suppose that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. We want to determine whether the surface described by this equation is an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid). As it turns out, this happens exactly when the matrix $A$ (with entries $a_{ij}$) is positive definite. Note that our equation can also be written in the form $x^TAx = 1$.

---

As a warm-up, let's consider the $2$-dimensional version of the problem. When does the equation
$$
a_{11}x_1^2 + 2a_{12} x_1x_2 + a_{22}x_2^2 = 1
$$
describe an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)? As before, this occurs when the matrix $A$ is positive definite, but let's try to see why this is the case. By Sylvester's criterion, $A$ will be positive definite if and only if $a_{11} > 0$ and $a_{11}a_{12} - a_{12}^2 > 0$. With this in mind, consider the quadratic function
$$
f(t) = a_{11} t^2 + 2a_{12}t + a_{22}.
$$
The fact that $a_{11} > 0$ tells us that the graph of this function is an upward-opening parabola. The fact that $a_{11}a_{12} - a_{12}^2 > 0$ tells us that this quadratic function does not have a real root, since its discriminant is given by
$$
b^2 - 4ac = 4(a_{12}^2 - a_{11}a_{22}) < 0.
$$
So, if we complete the square to rewrite $f(t)$ in "vertex form", then we should find that
$$
f(t) = a_{11}(t - h)^2 + k
$$
for some $k > 0$. Now, note that our original equation can be written in the form
$$
x_{2}^2 \cdot f(x_1/x_2) = 1.
$$
With our rewritten quadratic, this is now the equation
$$
a_{11}(x_1 - hx_2)^2 + k x_2^2 = 1.
$$
In other words, the positive definiteness of $A$ is important because it ensures that $x^TAx$ is *a sum of squares*.

Another way to think about the new equation is as follows. We made a substitution
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} = \pmatrix{1 & -h\\0 & 1} \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2}
$$
such that the new equation was of the form
$$
b_{11} y_1^2 + b_{22}y_2^2
$$
for some positive $b_{11},b_{22}$. To put this another way, we found that
$$
P = \pmatrix{1 & -h\\0 & 1} \implies P^TAP = \pmatrix{b_{11} & 0\\0 & b_{22}}.
$$

---

Now, is there some way that we can use our result for $2$-D space for $3$-D space? One idea is to make a substitution that gets us "halfway there". That is, perhaps we can find a $3 \times 3$ invertible matrix $P$ such that the substitution
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\y_3} = P \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}
$$
yields an equation of the form
$$
b_{11}y_1^2 + (b_{22}y_2^2 + 2b_{23}y_2y_3 + b_{33}y_3^2) = 1.
$$
From there, all we'd need to do is apply our approach from last time on the expression $b_{22}y_2^2 + 2b_{23}y_2y_3 + b_{33}y_3^2$.  This is exactly what the Schur complement does for us! Partition $A$ into the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{a_{11} & v\\ v^T & M}.
$$

We know that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
PAP^T = \pmatrix{a_{11} & 0\\0 & M - a_{11}^{-1} vv^T} = \pmatrix{b_{11} & 0 & 0\\0 & b_{22} & b_{23}\\0 & b_{23} & b_{33}}.
$$
Correspondingly, making the substitution $y = Px$ leads to an equation in the form that we wanted, and now all that's left to do is check if $a_{11}$ is positive and the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{b_{22} & b_{23}\\ b_{23} & b_{33}}$ is positive definite.