# Bounds on the eigenvalues of $\bf W D W^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Given a diagonal matrix $\bf D$ with diagonal entries $d_{ii} \in [0,1]$ and a matrix $\bf W$ with singular values $\sigma_i ({\bf W}) \in [0,1]$, can it be proven that the eigenvalues of $\bf W D W^\top$ lie in the interval $[0,1]$?

It's worth noting that $\bf W D W^\top$ is positive semidefinite, ensuring real non-negative eigenvalues.

Any insights or proofs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the diagonal entries of D are non-negative. but if they were positive, there is a way to prove that the eigenvalues of $WDW^t$ lies in the interval [0,1]?

Comment: the matrices are given

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. To prove it, you can prove that $$\mathbf I - \mathbf W \mathbf D\mathbf W^\intercal \succeq 0$$

Indeed,

- $\mathbf W\mathbf W^{\intercal} - \mathbf W \mathbf D\mathbf W^\intercal = \mathbf W \underbrace{\left(\mathbf I - \mathbf D\right)}_{\succeq 0}\mathbf W^\intercal \succeq 0$
- The eigenvalues of $\mathbf W\mathbf W^\intercal$ are the singular values of $\mathbf W$ squared. Since these values lie in $[0, 1]$ then the eigenvalues of $\mathbf W\mathbf W^\intercal$ will also lie in $[0, 1]$ and that proves that, $$\mathbf I - \mathbf W\mathbf W^\intercal \succeq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you explain why the inequality $\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{W} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{W}^\intercal \succeq 0$ leads to the conclusion that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{W} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{W}^\intercal$ are all less than 1?

Comment: You are using $\mathbf I \succeq  \mathbf W\mathbf W^\intercal$ and $\mathbf W\mathbf W^{\intercal} \succeq \mathbf W \mathbf D\mathbf W^\intercal$ to conclude that $\mathbf I \succeq \mathbf W \mathbf D\mathbf W^\intercal$, right?

Comment: Yes or you can see the sum of the two matrices and you will find the first matrix

Comment: @korenabitbul since the eigenvalues of $\mathbf I$ are all equal to $1$ and the matrix that I show is a semidefinite positive matrix then all eigenvalues of your matrix are smaller than $1$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4739635/339790)