# On the transitivity of the Löwner order

Tags: matrices, reference-request, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

If the [Löwner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order) is a partial order, then it is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). If so, how can one prove it?

---

**Proposition.** Let ${\Bbb S}_n ({\Bbb R})$ denote the set of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices over $\Bbb R$. The [Löwner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order) is transitive, i.e.,

$$ \left( \forall {\bf A}, {\bf B}, {\bf C} \in {\Bbb S}_n ({\Bbb R}) \right) \left( ({\bf A} \succeq {\bf B}) \land ({\bf B} \succeq {\bf C}) \implies {\bf A} \succeq {\bf C} \right) $$

---

**Proof.** The proposition can be rewritten as follows

$$ \left( \forall {\bf A}, {\bf B}, {\bf C} \in {\Bbb S}_n ({\Bbb R}) \right) \left( \left({\bf A} - {\bf B} \succeq {\bf O}_n \right) \land \left({\bf B} - {\bf C} \succeq {\bf O}_n \right) \implies {\bf A} - {\bf C} \succeq {\bf O}_n \right) $$

Since the addition of symmetric positive semidefinite matrices [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/544139/339790) symmetric positive semidefinite,

$$ \underbrace{(\overbrace{{\bf A} - {\bf B}}^{\succeq {\bf O}_n}) + (\overbrace{{\bf B} - {\bf C}}^{\succeq {\bf O}_n})}_{\succeq {\bf O}_n} = {\bf A} - {\bf C} \succeq {\bf O}_n \implies {\bf A} \succeq {\bf C} $$

---

Assuming that the proof above is correct, I am looking for alternative proofs or references.

---

**Related:** [What does "curly (curved) less than" sign $\succcurlyeq$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669085/339790)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. It seems to me that this will be the most elementary proof of the statement.

Comment: @Youem If there are no interesting alternative proofs, that is fine. The purpose of this question is to have a post on Mathematics SE which people can link to whenever someone uses the transitivity of the Löwner order without proof / reference.